# How to integrate JUnit into already developed application?

Tags: java, junit4

I'm very much new to JUnit. We want to integrate JUnit into our old and big Enterprise Java application(which has many projects associated with it) developed long back.We want to do it without touching java files and on framework level. Is it possible? If yes, please share me the links or information on how to do it?

Comment: "We want to do it without touching java files and on framework level." Not everything is testable out of the box. Especially when "big and old" ...

Comment: Thanks Fildor. Could you please elaborate your reply?

Comment: You can write tests, but what do you want to test? Obviously it has nothing to do with TDD. Could you explain what you exactly mean by "on framework level"?

Comment: You don't have to edit any Java files to perform unit testing on them.  Unless there is something that is not accessible, e.g. privates, in which case you need to decide whether to edit the file or not test it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment (yet) so here is my recommendation as an answer:

**"Working Effectively with Legacy Code"** by Michael Feathers covers all scenarios of testing / maintaining etc. of old, huge applications in a very readable way.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you touch existing Java files for writing unit tests ( if you are ready to leave non-testable classes in your source as they are) ?

Isn't **integrate JUnit** means writing unit tests for existing classes using `JUnit` ( for which unit tests have not been written so far) **OR** is there any other meaning you intend too?.

We keep test classes written using `JUnit` in a separate `source-folder` so those don't mess with your existing code.

I don't see any concern here. Just add `JUnit` jar into your project's build path ( by including jar OR by adding `maven dependency` OR by adding `Gradle` dependency ) and start writing unit tests for your testable classes and you are done with your integration.

You might choose to not include `source-folder-for-tests` into your deployment build.

Sometimes in your old code, some classes might not be testable so you will have to tweak those a little if wish to cover those too.

Hope it helps !!